# Pulse effect using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

Trying to create a pulse effect with a canvas object with plain vanilla javascript. Each function seems to be calling properly and all my values are logging right, but for some reason when the drawBall() function is called in the ballShrink() function nothing happens. I am expecting it to animate to shrink but it doesn't. ballRadius is reducing but no animation occurs. I have my code here and a JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/96hthyw0/

```
function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawBall();
  }

function ballGrow() {
    ballRadius += 1;
    drawBall();
    if (ballRadius === 20)  {
        clearInterval(ballGrowInterval);
        ballShrinkInterval = setInterval(ballShrink, 100);
    } 
}

function ballShrink()   {
    ballRadius -= 1;
    drawBall();
    if (ballRadius === 0)   {
       clearInterval(ballShrinkInterval);
    }
}

function testInterval() {
    ballGrowInterval = setInterval(ballGrow, 100);
}  

testInterval();
draw();
```

Comment: Why are you not using CSS3 animations? You can do that behavior with just a couple of lines with CSS

Comment: See e.g. this page for CSS spinners: http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're not clearing your last drawing but just adding new drawings on top of the existing one. Here is an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96hthyw0/1/ but in short all I did was change your `ballShrink` function to this:

```
function ballShrink()   {
  ballRadius -= 1;
  draw(); // clear canvas - note you could add this to ball grow too
  drawBall();
  if (ballRadius === 0) {
    clearInterval(ballShrinkInterval);
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for that @winhowes. It makes sense now.